# Selecting a Column from a Row from a previous Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm really sorry if this is a simple fix but I'm completely stumped, probably suffering from a temporary block.

Anyway, my predicament goes like this, my website has a page that includes events, I, of course, have an events table which has the following fields:

```
    EventID
    EventName
    EventStart
    EventEnd
    EventDesc
```

Now my first query, is to make sure I collect all events that haven't ended yet. Make sense?

I am then doing a `for` which looks like this:
`for($i=0;$i<$numr;$i++)` - $numr is defined as - `$numr = mysqli_num_rows($sql)` and you can guess what $sql is? Just to be safe: `$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE EventEnd >= NOW()")`

Inside this `for` loop, I intend to create multiple `<option>` tags for however many events there are. So far so good, it looks like this: `echo "<option id='" . $i . "' name='" . $i . "' value='" . $i . "'>`

That's where my problem is, I know need to get the `EventName` of the FIRST row that was returned from the sql query. I am unsure of how to do this? My initially thought was to use an array and store the names there, however, I am not 100% familiar with arrays in php.

Is there a way you guys can help me out here? Again I'm really sorry if this is just a basic function I need to use or something but I'm having real problems right now.

Thanks so much guys!
Mike.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787681/how-do-i-loop-through-a-php-array-containing-data-returned-from-mysql

Comment: I knew it was probably something silly! Thanks David! I'll comment back if anything else occurs. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [fetch_assoc doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Instead of

```
for($i=0;$i<$numr;$i++) {
    //echoing options
}
```

do

```
while($event = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option id='" . $event['EventID'] . "' value='" . $event['EventName'] . "'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside your for loop: `$first name = null;`

Inside your loop:

```
if(empty($first_name))
    $first_name = $row['EventName'];
```