# PHP Ajax return more than one row from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I wrote some PHP and Ajax code in order to see my inventory when I type in a location name. Here is an image of my inventory. Notice most of the locations contain more than one kind of items.

[image]

And here is the front end interface I have. 
[image]

Here's the part of the code I have problems with.

```
<?php
    // '.post' could be '.get' here but global.js has to be the same, .post is faster
    if(isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {
        require '../db/connect.php';

        $query = mysql_query("
            SELECT `sheet0_100`.`id`
            FROM `sheet0_100`
            WHERE `sheet0_100`.`location` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) . "'
        ");
        echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_fetch_row($query) : 'Location not found..';


    }
?>
```

If you notice **mysql_fetch_row** part, when I type in a location, for instance, 50A-3, it returns a word "Array" instead of the record. Same result for those locations have more than one rows. I wonder what do I have to do with **$query** so that the webpage can display all the rows from a location? Thanks!

Comment: Firstable stop using mysql_*. It is deprecated. mysql_fetch_row returns array, so you could use echo print_r(mysql_fetch_row($query),1); if you want to see it

Comment: You would also need to iterate the entire result set. Calling fetch_row on each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use the mysql_* extension functions, in order to retrieve and therefor display multiple rows, use a `while` loop:

```
<?php
// '.post' could be '.get' here but global.js has to be the same, .post is faster
if(isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {
    require '../db/connect.php';

    $query = mysql_query("
        SELECT `sheet0_100`.`id`
        FROM `sheet0_100`
        WHERE `sheet0_100`.`location` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) . "'
    ");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
            // output results using the $row array
        }
    }
    else {
        echo('Location not found..');
    };          

}
?>
```

`mysql_fetch_row` fetches each row one at a time

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/787688/1430996